# Solve integral $ \int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi \sqrt{5+4\sin\theta}\,d\theta $

Tags: integration, problem-solving

I need to solve the next integral:

$$ \int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi \sqrt{5+4\sin\theta}~\mathrm d\theta  $$

Thanks for help

Comment: Could you add some context to this question? What have you tried? What are you struggling with? Is there some background that might be useful for this problem?

Comment: I try to calculate length of curve $$ r=2+sin\theta $$

Comment: this leads to an elliptic function

Comment: Maple says this here $$2/3\,{\it EllipticPi} \left( 3/10\,\sqrt {10},{\frac {8}{9}},2/3\,
\sqrt {2} \right) +6\,{\it EllipticE} \left( 2/3\,\sqrt {2} \right) +6
\,{\it EllipticE} \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2},2/3\,\sqrt {2} \right) 
$$

Comment: indefinite integral is not elementary https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bsqrt(5+%2B+4SIN(t)),%7Bt,-Pi,Pi%7D%5D

Comment: *Mathematica* gives:  $4 \left(E\left(\left.\frac{\pi }{4}\right|-8\right)+3 E\left(\frac{\pi}{4}|\frac{8}{9}\right)\right)$

Comment: You need to *EVALUATE* the integral, i.e. to find the value of the integral.

Comment: The EVALUATION of the integral is in terms of EllipticPi functions, as I wrote.  If you plug in the values (or perform a *numerical* integration) you find the numerical value is $13.3649$.

Comment: Would utilizing a numerical method, like Composite Simpson's Rule, help you?

Comment: Its an exercise from homework. It is not expected to know how to evaluate integral or need to use wolform. Like I said, I try to calculate length of curve. Maybe can do integral much easier to solve before that, I don't know. 
@Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: My fault. I need to calculate the area between the curve. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have,

$$\sqrt{5} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sqrt{1+\frac{4}{5}\sin \theta} d\theta$$

$$=\sqrt{5} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sum_{n \geq 0} {\frac{1}{2} \choose n} (\frac{4}{5})^n \sin^n x dx$$

$$=\sqrt{5} \sum_{n \geq 0} {\frac{1}{2} \choose n} (\frac{4}{5})^n F(n)$$

Where $F(n)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin^n x dx$.

Note $F(n)=0$ for $n$ odd as $\sin^n x$ is then odd. Also note for $n$ even,

$$F(n)=2 \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^n x dx=4 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^n x dx$$

Show that for $n \geq 2$,

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{n} x dx=\frac{n-1}{n} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{n-2} dx$$

Use this to show for $n \geq 2$ even we have,

$$F(n)=\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdots (n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdots n} (2\pi)$$

That gives,

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sqrt{5+4\sin \theta} d\theta$$

$$=2\pi \sqrt{5} (1+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n+1}{2} {\frac{1}{2} \choose n} (\frac{4}{5})^n \frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!})$$

Or equally with the definition $(-1)!!=1$ and $(0)!!=1$:

$$=2\pi \sqrt{5} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2} {\frac{1}{2} \choose n} (\frac{4}{5})^n \frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}$$

With some terms one can get a good approximation to what Wolfram Alpha [gets](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Cpi%20%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%20%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%28-1%29%5En%2B1%7D%7B2%7D%20%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%20%5Cchoose%20n%7D%20%28%5Cfrac%7B4%7D%7B5%7D%29%5En%20%5Cfrac%7B%28n-1%29%21%21%7D%7Bn%21%21%7D&x=0&y=0).

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately, I am looking for solution that much more Conventional. please take a look at my last comment above.

Comment: Perhaps you copied the integral down wrong? Integrals like these have been proven not expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I just use the formula to calculate length of curve: 
$$ r=2+sin\theta $$

Comment: It looks good to me, are you sure they ask you to compute the integral?

Comment: Ok I checked again and you are right, I confused. I need to calculate the area between the curve. my fault.